# Efficiently capture screen data and control mouse movements (think game bot)

Tags: swift, automation, screenshot, pyautogui

I'm thinking about building out a simple library to take in screen data and control the mouse and other peripherals accordingly. It could play games or automate various tasks. Just for fun. I'm looking into various tooling and have thusfar encountered `pyautogui` and the swift api. The swift api takes a screenshot in about 0.08 seconds on my laptop, `pyautogui` is much slower at 0.25. Is there a more efficient way to do this? 12.5 frames per second isn't ideal for FPS or anything super zippy. Even the builtin `screencapture` doesn't really push things:

```
$ time screencapture one.png

real    0m0.187s
user    0m0.091s
sys     0m0.016s
```

Any help?